# How to build OpenCv with extra contrib modules

Tags: android, windows, shell, opencv, cmd

I am trying to build OpenCV to include OpenCV contrib modules which is in a repository. I am following the instructions in [this link](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/README.md), but i could not understand the cmd commands which is i mentioned in the section titled "cmd commands" as follows.

**cmd commands**:

```
$ cd <opencv_build_directory>
$ cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=<opencv_contrib>/modules     
<opencv_source_directory>
$ make -j5
```

here are my attempts to get the cmd commands as mentioned above running:

1-concerning the *opencv_build_directory*: i just created it by myself and named it 'build' as shown in the image in the section titled "OpenCV3.0.0 source"

2-concerning the *opencv_source_directory*: i think it should be "OpenCV-android-sdk" as shown in the image section titled "OpenCV3.0.0 source"

3- for the cmd command '$ cd ' i set it as follows:

```
c:\xxxx\libs\OpenCV-3.0.0-android-sdk-1\OpenCV-android-sdk\build>
```

4- for the cmd command '$ cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/modules' iset it as follows:

```
 cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=opencv_contrib-master/modules OpenCV-
 android-sdk
```

the entire command i type in the cmd is:

```
c:\xxxx\libs\OpenCV-3.0.0-android-sdk-1\OpenCV-android- 
sdk\build>cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=opencv_contrib-
master/modules OpenCV-android-sdk
```

but after running it, i get:

```
CMake Error: The source directory "C:/xxxx/libs/OpenCV-3.0.0-
android-sdk-1/OpenCV-android-sdk/build/OpenCV-android-sdk" does not 
exist.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
```

please help me to build the path correctly as stated in the linke mentioned

**note**:

I am trying to install opencv contrib modules on android through android Studio

**OpenCV3.0.0 source**

[image]

**OpenCV-contrib source**:

[image]

Comment: Are you intentionally compiling for Android or is it just a mistake?

Comment: @saurabheights i am trying to install it on Android. why do u think it is a mistake

Comment: Well your question doesn't mention that you are trying to install for android. That's why I was confused about why you are using android version. I dont have any knowledge about how opencv installation is different for android. You should read my answer anyways and especially watch the videos. It will help you in understanding the build process of opencv. Then you can make changes easily according to  android opencv install guide: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/O4A_SDK.html